# tcp server using epoll gives non-socket error

Tags: c, networking, tcpserver, serve

i am creating a simple tcp echo server in c using `epoll`. while compiling it gives error:
`Socket operation on non-socket`

why does it gives `non-socket`? i tried but couldn't get my head around it.
below is my code and here is the [article that i am following](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/epoll-example.c)

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_LISTEN_BACKLOG 1
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096


int bind_and_create(char *port){
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int s, sfd;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, port , &hints, &result);
    if( s != 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo :%s\n",gai_strerror(s));
        return -1;
    }

    for( rp = result; rp!= NULL; rp->ai_next){
          int sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,rp->ai_protocol);
      if ( sfd == -1)
          continue;
      s = bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr,rp->ai_addrlen);
      if ( s == 0){
          //succefull managed to bind socket
        break;
      }

          close(sfd);
        }

    if ( rp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"could not bind");
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return sfd;
    }


int make_socket_non_blocking( int sfd ){

    int flags , s;
    flags = fcntl(sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1){
        perror("fnctl error");
        return -1;
    }

    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    s = fcntl(sfd,F_SETFL,flags);
    if (s == -1){
        perror("fnctl error");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


#define MAXEVENTS 64

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sfd, s;
  int efd;
  struct epoll_event event;
  struct epoll_event *events;

  if (argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [port]\n", argv[0]);
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  sfd = bind_and_create (argv[1]);
  if (sfd == -1)
    abort ();

  s = make_socket_non_blocking (sfd);
  if (s == -1)
    abort ();

  s = listen (sfd, SOMAXCONN); // error is here but why????
  if (s == -1)
    {
      perror ("listen");
      abort ();
    }

  efd = epoll_create1 (0);
  if (efd == -1)
    {
      perror ("epoll_create");
      abort ();
    }

  event.data.fd = sfd;
  event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
  s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &event);
  if (s == -1)
    {
      perror ("epoll_ctl");
      abort ();
    }

  /* Buffer where events are returned */
  events = calloc (MAXEVENTS, sizeof event);

  /* The event loop */
  while (1)
    {
      int n, i;

      n = epoll_wait (efd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if ((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) ||
              (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) ||
              (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)))
        {
              /* An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
                 ready for reading (why were we notified then?) */
          fprintf (stderr, "epoll error\n");
          close (events[i].data.fd);
          continue;
        }

      else if (sfd == events[i].data.fd)
        {
              /* We have a notification on the listening socket, which
                 means one or more incoming connections. */
              while (1)
                {
                  struct sockaddr in_addr;
                  socklen_t in_len;
                  int infd;
                  char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

                  in_len = sizeof in_addr;
                  infd = accept (sfd, &in_addr, &in_len);
                  if (infd == -1)
                    {
                      if ((errno == EAGAIN) ||
                          (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
                        {
                          /* We have processed all incoming
                             connections. */
                          break;
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          perror ("accept");
                          break;
                        }
                    }

                  s = getnameinfo (&in_addr, in_len,
                                   hbuf, sizeof hbuf,
                                   sbuf, sizeof sbuf,
                                   NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
                  if (s == 0)
                    {
                      printf("Accepted connection on descriptor %d "
                             "(host=%s, port=%s)\n", infd, hbuf, sbuf);
                    }

                  /* Make the incoming socket non-blocking and add it to the
                     list of fds to monitor. */
                  s = make_socket_non_blocking (infd);
                  if (s == -1)
                    abort ();

                  event.data.fd = infd;
                  event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                  s = epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &event);
                  if (s == -1)
                    {
                      perror ("epoll_ctl");
                      abort ();
                    }
                }
              continue;
            }
          else
            {
              /* We have data on the fd waiting to be read. Read and
                 display it. We must read whatever data is available
                 completely, as we are running in edge-triggered mode
                 and won't get a notification again for the same
                 data. */
              int done = 0;

              while (1)
                {
                  ssize_t count;
                  char buf[512];

                  count = read (events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof buf);
                  if (count == -1)
                    {
                      /* If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
                         data. So go back to the main loop. */
                      if (errno != EAGAIN)
                        {
                          perror ("read");
                          done = 1;
                        }
                      break;
                    }
                  else if (count == 0)
                    {
                      /* End of file. The remote has closed the
                         connection. */
                      done = 1;
                      break;
                    }

                  /* Write the buffer to standard output */
                  s = write (1, buf, count);
                  if (s == -1)
                    {
                      perror ("write");
                      abort ();
                    }
                }

              if (done)
                {
                  printf ("Closed connection on descriptor %d\n",
                          events[i].data.fd);

                  /* Closing the descriptor will make epoll remove it
                     from the set of descriptors which are monitored. */
                  close (events[i].data.fd);
                }
            }
        }
    }

  free (events);

  close (sfd);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int bind_and_create(char *port){
    ...
    int s, sfd; // <- one sfd
    ...
    for( rp = result; rp!= NULL; rp->ai_next){ // <- rp->ai_next has no effect
        int sfd = socket(...); // <-- two sfd
        ...
        close(sfd); // <-- two sfd gone
    }   
    ...
    return sfd; // <-- one sfd, still completely uninitialised
}
```

If you want to stop wasting your time on this, **use -Wall or an equivalent compiler setting**.

Comment: thanks i understood now and also thanks for mentioning about `-Wall` will definitely use it .

Comment: also why is  `rp->ai_next` unused.is there any other way of iterating?

Comment: `rp->ai_next` is an expression. You want to change a pointer to point to the next list item but `rp->ai_next` changes nothing.